Placing label next to a slider handle
I want a label near the slider's handle, that displays the current value. I used the code provided on the forum and tried to adapt it to Python
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class test(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.main_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Vertical,self)
        self.slider.setMaximum(100)
        self.slider.setMinimum(0)
        self.slider.setTracking(True)
        self.label= QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("label")
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.slider,0,QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label,0,QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.updateLabel(0)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.updateLabel)


    def updateLabel(self,value):
        height= QtWidgets.QStyle.sliderPositionFromValue(0,100,self.slider.value(),self.slider.height()-self.label.height(), True)
        self.label.move(self.slider.width(), height)
        self.label.setText(str(value))


    def resizeEvent(self,ev):

        self.updateLabel(self.slider.sliderPosition())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = test()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

As a result, I get a label with value, but it is always shown at the bottom of the window.

Once I resize my window, the label moves to the correct place.

Do I miss something?

Remove the label from the layout. You're managing the position of the label yourself, so you don't want the layout to interfere with that.

To add on @ekhumoro's comment: Simply removing the line self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label,0,QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom) should do the trick.

With the help of @ekhumoro and @simon, I fixed the problem
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class test(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.main_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Vertical,self)
        self.slider.setMaximum(100)
        self.slider.setMinimum(0)
        self.slider.setTracking(True)
        self.label= QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("label")
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.slider,0,QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.updateLabel(0)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.updateLabel)


    def updateLabel(self,value):
        height= QtWidgets.QStyle.sliderPositionFromValue(0,100,self.slider.value(),self.slider.height()-self.label.height(), True)
        self.label.move(self.slider.width(), height)
        self.label.setText(str(value))


    def resizeEvent(self,ev):

        self.updateLabel(self.slider.sliderPosition())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = test()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


The main difference is not adding the Qlabel inside of the layout, hence having more direct control over its location. One would need to account for label size while using the widget, since by default it's size shrinks to QSlider size

To fix the width issue, override minimumSizeHint(), get the current size hint with super().minimumSizeHint(), then update the width considering that of the label before returning.
